# Confusion regarding CRF

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process

I was reading this paper related to conditional random fields http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/hmw26/papers/crf_intro.pdf. However, I have some confusion related to the section CRF probability as matrix computation. I couldn't actually grasp how it all fits in

Can anyone please provide an example or two so that I can understand how it all fits in?